# How to redirect website.com/ and website.com/index.php to another page with htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I can redirect `website.com/index.php` to `website.com/home` but I can't find a way to redirect `website.com` to `website.com/home`

I have tried `RewriteRule ^/$ /home [R=301]` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single rule can handle both redirects:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /home [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://www.website.com/home [R=301,L]
```

This rule redirects www.website.com to www.website.com/home

Or add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [R=301,L]
```